# Why my request can't response my input data?

Tags: python, flask, request

I run `request_data.py`, but I can't find my input data `Nakano` on my output data, what should I do?

request_data.py

```
import requests
params = {'user' : 'Nakano'}
response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', data = params)
print(response.text)
```

the output is：

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

the flask server：

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
     return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def result():
     if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.values['user']
        return render_template('result.html', name=user)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1')
```

login.html：

```
<body style="background-color: black">
    <form method="post" action="/login">
        <input type="text" name="user">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

result.html：

```
<body style="background-color: black">
     <p style="color: white">Your user name is {{ name }}</p>
</body>
```

Comment: In `request_data` you request to `/` in `POST` there is no route for that. you have `POST /login` and `GET /` only. I guess you want `requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/login', data = params)`

Comment: Also no need to `if request.method == 'POST':` if you specify only `POST` in the route definiton 2 lines above

Comment: Thanks, it can work. But why need to add `/login` ?

Comment: Because that is the route you defined in your server

Comment: I known, thank you